# laravel get all hours where value exits or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, select

here is my laravel DB query

```
DB::table ( 'zee_hours' )
->select (
    [
        'zee_hours.hours',
        DB::raw ( 'COALESCE(count(zee_shipment_events.amazon_order_id),0)' ),
    ] )
->leftJoin ( 'zee_shipment_events', 'zee_hours.hours', '=', DB::raw ( 'HOUR(zee_shipment_events.pdate)' ) )
->join ( 'zee_shipment_items', 'zee_shipment_items.shipment_id', '=', 'zee_shipment_events.id' )
->join ( 'zee_promotions', 'zee_promotions.shipment_item_id', '=', 'zee_shipment_items.id' )

->groupBy ( 'zee_hours.hours' )
->get ();
```

**Problem**
this way, I am only able to get those hours where some order was placed.

what I want is, I need even those hours where no order was placed (showing 0 with them)

Have tried hard, but still, no way

Comment: just speaking for myself here, but you're really going to have to dumb down the question to be more basic or at least refactor it slightly if you want some help. Right now my head hurts just reading it

Comment: tried to edit it to your taste

Comment: Handle the logic of missing values in your application code, e.g. a simple loop

Comment: This is not related to Laravel in any way. It's a basic programming question